# WooCommerce trigger all orders update

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to trigger action **save_post_shop_order** by url, because I have custom function that will create product meta there on checking.

I tried something like:

```
add_action('wp_head', 'update_orders_by_url');
function update_orders_by_url() {
    if( isset( $_GET['update_woo_orders'] ) ) {
    $query = new WC_Order_Query( array(
        'limit' => -1
    ));
    
    $orders = $query->get_orders();
    
    foreach($orders as $order){
         $arra2[] = $order;
                    
    // Save
    $order->save();

    }
}
    //echo count($arra2);
}
```

But seems not working in my case.
How I can trigger update all orders and run action **save_post_shop_order** for all orders?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To update orders information through the URL, you can try the following steps.

> 1. Create a file in your root directory

On the top of the file, add this piece of code.

`require(dirname(__FILE__) . '/wp-load.php');`

> 2. Get all orders

```
$orders = wc_get_orders( array('numberposts' => -1) );

// Loop through each WC_Order object
foreach( $orders as $order ){
    echo $order->get_id() . '<br>'; // The order ID
    echo $order->get_status() . '<br>'; // The order status
    .......
    // do your stuff
}
```

> 3. Now, you will be able to update orders information through `URL`.
>    Hit your url/pagename, for example, `http://example.com/test.php`

Comment: Should this file be in same folder contain wp-content, wp-admin?

Comment: Yes, the main folder, such as public_html or project main folder.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it this way, put your code in `functions.php` or a `plugin`

```
 add_filter( 'handle_bulk_actions-edit-shop_order', 'save_post_shop_order', 10, 3 );
 /**
  * @param $redirect_to
  * @param $action
  * @param $post_ids
  * @return mixed|string
  */
 function save_post_shop_order( $redirect_to, $action, $post_ids ) {

      // do your job




       return $redirect_to = add_query_arg( array(
            'bulk_action_name' => $action,
            'processed_count' => count( $processed_ids ),
            'processed_ids' => implode( ',', $processed_ids ),
        ), $redirect_to );
 }


add_action( 'admin_notices', 'save_post_shop_order_admin_notice' );
 /**
  *  The results notice from bulk action on orders
  */
function save_post_shop_order_admin_notice() {

  $count = intval( $_REQUEST['processed_count'] );

  printf( '<div id="message" class="updated fade"><p>' .
      _n( "",
          "",
          $count,
          ''
      ) . '</p></div>', $count );
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but does not fired my action unfortunatelly :(